# Rails selectize Gem installation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, selectize.js

Trying to add selectize

Source: http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/

Gem source: https://github.com/manuelvanrijn/selectize-rails

Added to Gemfile:

```
gem "selectize-rails"
```

Added application.js

```
//= require selectize
```

Added to application.css

```
 *= require selectize
 *= require selectize.default
```

My form:

```
  <%= f.select :user, User.not_god.map{|u| [u.to_s, u.id]}, { id: 'user-select' } %>
```

My JS:

```
    $('#user-select').selectize({ <-- Uncaught 
                                  TypeError: 
                                  undefined is not a function
      create: true,
      sortField: 'text'
    });
```

This is giving me `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Did anyone encounter this with selectize?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assigning the HTML `id` attribute inside the `options` hash; you want to assign it inside the `html_options` hash. Try passing an empty hash for `options`:

```
<%= f.select(
  :user, 
  User.not_god.map{|u| [u.to_s, u.id]}, 
  {}, 
  { id: 'user-select' } 
 ) %>
```

Take a look at the docs to see the order of the formal arguments.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select

Edit:

Also, check that your `jQuery`, `selectize`, and custom scripts are being loaded in the correct order.

**app/assets/javascripts/application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require selectize

$(function() {
  $('#user-select').selectize({
    create: true,
    sortField: 'text'
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, any idea why the JS is outputting errors?

Comment: Also, what version of `selectize-rails` are you using?

Comment: on  selectize-rails (0.12.0), what would be the correct order? jQuery first? then selectize?

Comment: Updated answer. Yes, that order.

Comment: `
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require selectize
` that's what I have

Comment: I am able to get it working, so I doubt it's an issue with `selectize-rails`. It appears your issue will require some debugging; not sure if SO is the best place for that. You could try posting a link to a GitHub repository and someone may be able to look at your code. If you feel your code is correct, you could raise and issue on the `selectize-rails` repository and provide as much detail as you can.